# Is there a good reason not to think of gravity as the signaling of particles inward motion?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, elementary-particles

This is not about inventing new theories, let alone rejecting canonical ones.

I am just wondering if general relativity (GR) could be interpreted like the following, or if there is something in GR that makes this interpretation impossible.

Also **the point is not to discuss if there is such an inward motion or not**. I am only asking if this would contradict GR.

So here it goes. Since charged particles emit a photon when they are accelerated, effectively signaling a change in the particle velocity, and those signals are able, in turn, to set particles in motion, I thought, if a particle is falling on itself, in an inward motion (introversion), why would it not transmit a signal about it, and why would it not be a "signal of motion" in the direction of the sink, effectively pulling the other particles it meets?

There is a similar proposal in the black hole electron hypothesis, and as Wikipedia mentions:
"A paper published in 1938 by Albert Einstein, Leopold Infeld and Banesh Hoffmann showed that if elementary particles are treated as singularities in spacetime, it is unnecessary to postulate geodesic motion as part of general relativity"

Here I am not saying what if particles were black holes. I am just asking, if they had a inward motion and some signal was spread because of it, would that be contradictory to gravity as described by GR.

GR, as far I know, is not a theory about microscopic gravity. So maybe it allows for this microscopic interpretation (or not).

Comment: What is "GM"?  Do you mean "GR"?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Fixing this immediately. I think I read too many articles about general motors recently.